Broadcom HBA 9500-16i and HDD disconnections
I experience random HDD disconnections. The workstation has:

Broadcom HBA 9500-16i
16 HDD seagate and WD, 16-18TB, sata connected
1 sata cable from PSU to 14 HDD, another to 2 HDD
Seasonic gold focus PSU 850W
Windows 10 enterprise

What could the the cause ? How to diagnostic this for certain ?
I suspect HDD power supply disbalance. If that's the case, is it a good practice to parallel connect the SATA power from the PSU ? Or prefer to split in a more even way (eg: 14+2 (14HDD supplied by one cable, +2 HDD powered by one other cable) to 12+4 up to 8+8) ?
